# LiftMaster Formula 1 intermittent remote control problems

Tags: garage-door-opener

We own four of the LiftMaster Formula 1 openers and none of the remotes are battery-powered. (we use the remotes build into the vehicles)
All of the bulbs in the openers are incandescent and the ones in the garage are CFL and the openers have worked flawlessly for years. Of late mine has been really intermittent. I can be parked underneath the opener and open/close the door using  the remote without issue but when I back out it's impossible to close the door even from one foot outside the garage. Then if I leave it open, run an errand and come back X minutes later and accidentally push the remote (on autopilot) it will close the door but then I cannot reopen from the door. Conversely, if I get out of my car, go into the garage and close the door using the hardwired  control then come back X minutes later - my remote will open the door. It's very frustrating and confusing. 
I might add that it's been exceptionally hot and humid so  this problem may be moisture related. 
Regardless, this same thing happened several years ago and I called our local dealer - they sold me a hard CB radio-like antenna to replace the wire with. Of course as soon as I had it in hand the problem went away so I haven't installed it yet but after reading these posts I don't think it's going to resolve my problems. 
Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have already read the numerous things people have noted. They could all be factors. As far as CFL... do a simple test, remove them. Literally unscrew. Repeat your testing. Any Changes? Also, When this happens, Does the other vehicle remote have an issue? How about the battery remote? I presume you have one. Try it just for sanity sake. Also, YOUR vehicle, try programming a different button for the door as well. Just to rule out a button issue. All that said, you could have an issue with your unit in your car, but do those other tests first.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. I installed the CB like antenna yesterday with no improvement.  I believe it is installed correctly as it worked one time. The brass core is attached to the antenna for the opener and the grounding strap is attached to the rail...

Comment: My wife's car also has intermittent problems but not nearly as severe as mine. I've also tried programming a different button on my car's remote. Oddly, I was unable to successfully do so.

Comment: The programming issue is probably related to the interference issue. Did you remove the CFLs? (literally unscrew them). Do you have any other electrical devices running off of the same AC circuit as the opener, e.g., a motor driven item like a freezer, or even a computer power supply? Do you have any OLD cordless phones, intercoms, baby monitor, or even an older wifi router? Does the unit have a battery backup - if so, does it work flawlessly off of battery? (unplug AC)

Comment: why not try installing the new antenna? It might not work, but you won't know until you try.

Comment: You should try using the antenna.  Why would you disregard what an expert has told you in favor of strangers on the web ?  It is obviously RF interference.  An antenna may well fix it.  So, will tracking the source of the noise and removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your system may be experiencing intermittent radio frequency interference from a nearby transmitter or remote control device.

Answer (score -2):

If you have an LED light bulb it will interfere with the remote and keyless entry frequency

Comment: I would go more with "can" interfere than "will" interfere, but I'd agree.

Comment: Note that the OP specifically indicated he has CFL & incandescent bulbs in the garage, _NOT_ LED.